# Why do popular series end?

Tags: analysis, friends, how-i-met-your-mother, two-and-a-half-men

Popular TV series such as *Friends*, *How I Met Your Mother*, *Two And A Half Men* all came to an end.

Why is that happened, when they could have continued?

1. Popular serials have the financial resources to continue.
2. new story-lines can be added.
3. New actors can be introduced.

Serials in Indian subcontinent run as long as they can, sometime for more than 20 years by adding new stories,characters and time leaps

Why couldn't American serials do that too?

Comment: So that they can end it on an all time high such that it is remembered for how great it is rather than like final seasons of "Dexter" which ruined Dexter for everyone...

Comment: @NikhilEshvar Added to your list, Lost,Heroes, Big Bang Theory

Comment: Hey I like this question :D !

Comment: @NikhilEshvar Not everyone. I loved Dexters' ending. He became a "real boy". (did you know Jeff Lindsay almost called his book series Pincchio Bleeds?!) Also I think they barrowed from JL's tropical depression novel (hurricane) and the pyschopathic family aspects were closer to how the books were.

Comment: It's for various reasons. Sometimes it's the EPs wanting to go out on a good note, sometimes it's production costs in relation to new series deals during Pilot season (network tv), sometimes the actors want out or price increase to stay...

Comment: I think _How I Met Your Mother_ should be fairly obvious.  The **entire** series has a point.  The last episode is literally _meeting the mother_.  The only way to keep the show going perpetually would be to make him _never_ find the mother, or change the plot completely during the series.  Neither seem like practical or profitable options.

Comment: The Friends main cast were paid ~$22,500 per episode in the first season, and kept increasing untill it reached $1 million in seasons nine and ten. Producing another season would've cost them a lot more.

Comment: Also, for the Friends case, the EPs tried making a [spin-off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joey_(TV_series)) to keep the spirit but failed after season 2.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir check about the pay rates for actors in big bang theory. it's a hugeeee.... and there are some other shows that pays more than 1 mil for actors per episode. They are getting payments like that because of show is doing well. that means show is a success. it's not a reason to stop a show. I mean producers ain't gonna pay from their own pockets forever.. only for one or two episodes at most!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It may be for various reasons

From `Wikipedia`,

> In television, cancellation refers to the termination of a program by
>   a network, typically because of low viewership, financial losses, or
>   unfavourable critical reviews. Other potential reasons for canceling
>   television programs include controversies involving the program's
>   cast, conflicts among the show's staff members or to make room for new
>   programming.

It also states that,

> Commercial television is supported by advertising, or viewers paying
>   for TV-channels. Viewing figures are collected by audience measurement
>   ratings agencies (such as Nielsen in the United States), and the
>   programs with the highest viewing figures command a higher advertising
>   fee for the network. As such, shows with a low viewership are
>   generally not as profitable.
>
> Other factors are considered as well, such as the cost to produce the
>   show.Very rarely are television programs cancelled for reasons other
>   than ratings or profitability. Four notable cases are Turn-On and
>   Australia's Naughtiest Home Videos, which were cancelled after viewer
>   and station outrage; Bridget Loves Bernie, forced off the air despite
>   high ratings because of threats of violence from Jewish radicals; Home
>   Run Derby, canceled due to the host's death; and Megan Wants a
>   Millionaire, which was axed in August 2009 following the arrest
>   warrant (and later, suicide) of one of the finalists.

*Read full article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_(television))*

---

So to sum up,Quoting `Vox`,

1. The show almost immediately flopped.
2. The show struggled in the ratings, and the studio wouldn't reduce the licensing fee.
3. The show struggled in the ratings and wasn't owned by the same corporation that owns its network.
4. The show had poor ratings and no syndication or streaming potential.
5. The show got poor ratings and was expensive.
6. The show got poor ratings, and nobody liked it (at the network).
7. The show just got too old.

*Read more [here](https://www.vox.com/culture/2017/5/16/15633120/why-tv-shows-get-canceled-ratings-arent-everything)*

Basically if a TV show cannot produce money, doing bad at ratings, or if story is finished, show is older and hard to continue, actors think now the time to stop are the most common reasons for the cancellation or end of the series.

**Note:**
Cancellation and Ending of a program is different.

**Added Notes:**

Read here for article about friends with Matthew Perry [here](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/06/13/matthew-perry-friends_n_3437232.html)

For Two and Half Men read [here](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/two-a-men-end-season-703963)

Comment: ... and House of Cards because of, emm, the actor that shall not be named.